# Convert Office document to the Office Open XML format

Tags: c#, ms-office

My scenario: I have a bunch of documents(powerpoint,word,excel) that needs to be converted to the Office Open  XML format .Is there any tool that will allow me to perform this tasks and if not can it be done using some C# codes?

Current document have the extensions doc,ppt,xls.

Comment: its Office Open XML @john

Comment: @john any recommendation for the solution in this case

Comment: I'd probably use the Office COM components to load the documents in one format and save them in the other format. It's been too long since I've worked with those (and that was in VBScript) to be able to give an answer. That's probably the most straight-forward option.